# what cygwin packages do I need to install to be able to run commands from cmd.exe on windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, cygwin, sh

I am trying to install [JSCover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jscover/files/JSCover-0.2.0.zip/download), I snooped around and figured that to run **.sh** files on windows, the easiest option is to install **cygwin**.
Which **cygwin** packages do I need to install to be able to run commands from **cmd.exe** on windows?
If it is unclear what packages I am talking about please check screenshot below.

[image]

**UPDATE:** I have tried default packages by clicking next in widow above. When I try to run `sh example-server.sh` in cmd in admin mode I get following error.
[image]

Or Cygwin installation only works within it's boundaries. e.g only things in Cygwin console window?

Comment: have you tried the normal packages? http://cygwin.com/install.html

Comment: I did. When I try to run sh example-server.sh in cmd in admin mode I get: 'sh' is not recognised as internal command... error.

Comment: if you are using ubuntu, you do not need to have sh as a command, just run the file: `>> example-server.sh` or `>> sudo example-server.sh`

Comment: I am running on Windows 7

Comment: Running sh is only native inside Cygwin.  Click the Cygwin Shortcut on your Desktop then download the file natively using a tool like wget in cygwin, then run the script, otherwise run the jar file natively in Windows

Comment: @ECarterYoung Could you post it as an answer please.

Comment: Done, tried to be as thorough as possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running sh is only native inside Cygwin. Click the Cygwin Shortcut on your Desktop then download the file natively using a tool like wget in Cygwin, then run the script, otherwise run the jar file natively in Windows

[image: Cygwin Terminal]

As you can see, my programmer's Teststand in my Office has Cygwin installed because I miss my Gentoo Desktop at home.  The only thing that isn't native here is the DRush Command Prompt, so that I can fool w/ my website on my lunch break.  It contained the wget.exe that was added to my $PATH after installing the [Windows Compliant DRush](http://drush.ws/drush_windows_installer), but the same idea  applies if you used the Cygwin installer to fetch the wget package.  The $ indicates a bash prompt that will run scripts natively inside the window only. See [Chapter 3 of the Cygwin User's Guide](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygwin-ug-net.html) to understand how to get the output you may need out to Windows.

Use the wget you install to download the package in your post and it should download to your home directory.  Use `pwd` to find out what that directory is and the information from Chapter 3 to gather the output you need.  **UNLESS YOU'VE BEEN USING CYGWIN AWHILE, DO NOT** leave the cygwin terminal open while messing with the Windows Physical Location, and vice versa